# Progress Bar Bind Value

Tags: wpf, binding, progress-bar

Fixed.  Had to Bind both the Maximum and Value and it worked.  In the test I bound both to Int32 (did not test binding both to double). Microsoft I think this is a bug.

```
   <ProgressBar Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Maximum="{Binding Path=DF.WFBatchFolderStatus.DocCount}" Value="{Binding Path=DF.WFBatchFolderStatus.DocCountComplete}" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
```

What is protocol.  If I answer my own question should I delete the question?

I get an error when I try to bind Value for a Progress Bar.  XamlParseException 'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.Value' threw an exception.' Grid.Row 8 fails and Grid.Row 9 Fails.  When I put in fixed values (Grid.Row 6 and Grid.Row 7) it works.  I can retrieve the value I want to bind to in a TextBlock (Grid.Row 5).  I have tried binding to Double and Int 32.  According to the documentation Minimum, Maximum, and Value are double.  The calculated value it is failing on is 2 (and it fails on other values).  Thanks in advance and I will mark the answer.

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=DF.WFBatchFolderStatus.DocPctComplete, StringFormat='Document Pct Count:  {0}'}" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="40" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Minimum="0E0" Maximum="100E0" Value="60E0" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Path=DF.WFBatchFolderStatus.DocPctCompleteInt}" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Minimum="0E0" Maximum="100E0" Value="{Binding Path=DF.WFBatchFolderStatus.DocPctComplete}" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" /> 

    public Double DocPctComplete
    {
        get
        {
            if (BatchFolderStatus == enumBatchFolderStatus.Waiting) return 0;
            if (BatchFolderStatus == enumBatchFolderStatus.WaitQC) return 0;
            if (BatchFolderStatus == enumBatchFolderStatus.Complete) return 100;
            if (DocCount < 1) return 0;
            if (DocCountComplete < 1) return 0;
            double docPctComplete = (Convert.ToDouble(DocCountComplete) / Convert.ToDouble(DocCount)) * 100E0;
            Debug.WriteLine("docPctComplete " + docPctComplete.ToString());
            return docPctComplete;
        }
    }
    public Int32 DocPctCompleteInt
    {
        get
        {
            if (BatchFolderStatus == enumBatchFolderStatus.Waiting) return 0;
            if (BatchFolderStatus == enumBatchFolderStatus.WaitQC) return 0;
            if (BatchFolderStatus == enumBatchFolderStatus.Complete) return 100;
            if (DocCount < 1) return 0;
            if (DocCountComplete < 1) return 0;
            double docPctComplete = (Convert.ToDouble(DocCountComplete) / Convert.ToDouble(DocCount)) * 100E0;
            Debug.WriteLine("docPctComplete " + docPctComplete.ToString());
            Int32 docPctCompleteInt = Convert.ToInt32(docPctComplete);
            Debug.WriteLine("docPctCompleteInt " + docPctCompleteInt.ToString());
            return docPctCompleteInt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Protocol is to answer your own question and mark it as accepted, this way if someone is looking for an answer for a similar question he'll be redirected to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. Had to Bind both the Maximum and Value and it worked. In the test I bound both to Int32 (did not test binding both to double). Microsoft I think this is a bug.  If the Maximum is XAML but the Value in Bind it fails (or it failed for me).

Answer (score 0):

Is it expecting a Double from 0.0 to 1.0?

It shouldn't, but does that fix it?

Also, I usually specify Double constants in code like this: 0.0D, 1.0D, 100.0D

Comment: I tried taking off the 100 to feed it a value of .02 and that did not help.  I thought D was for Decimal (not Double) but I will try that.  I get a syntax error when I try and put in Maximum="100D".  It will take 100, 100E, or 100E0.

Comment: It's not very obvious in the documentation. I finally found it, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfft1t3c.aspx