# Setting C# xaml progress bar's maximum value to a variable value

Tags: c#, xaml, variables, max

I have a xaml progress bar in my code that I would like to set the maximum value equal to a int determined elsewhere in my code.  How may I do this?

```
<ProgressBar Name="pb_Run" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Margin="0,166,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="960" IsIndeterminate="False" Minimum="0" Maximum="**some_variable_value_here**"/>
```

Some additional information.  The variable value is determined after the xaml interface for the user selects a file.  It has the value equal to the count of the number of rows in the file. The progress bar increments by a fixed integer value at each update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress bar problem grew after this question.  I did not need to work with the xaml code. Ultimately setting the maximum value was as simple as adding the following code:

```
pb_Run.Maximum = loanCNT;
```

What became a bigger issue was how to increment the value of the progress bar.  It turns out incrementing the progress bar value to a for loop (tight loop) requires a dispatcher.  To that end the following code was added:

```
      UpdateProgressBarDelegate updatePbDelegate = new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(pb_Run.SetValue);
        pb_Run.Maximum = loanCNT;
        double progressBarValue=0;

    private delegate void UpdateProgressBarDelegate(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);
```

And the new for loop:

```
for (int obs = 0; obs < loanCNT; obs++)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    Processing.Run(new Loan(), line);
                    progressBarValue += 1;
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(updatePbDelegate,System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { ProgressBar.ValueProperty, progressBarValue });
                }
```

Hopefully this helps someone if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

you need to do something like this :

```
if(_needToChangeProgressBarValue)
{
    pb_Run.Maximum = yourvariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WPF's data bindnig to bind the maximum value of your progress bar with a value in your code behind.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7209631/2182203) for an example.